# viewDidLoad - Code optimization

Tags: iphone, optimization, memory-management, ios4

I have some code, but I can't see how I can optimize it. Allthough I know the code is badly written (by myself).

What I have is a list of train station names. What I want to do is add these station names to a tableview and have a section for every station name's first letter. Those sections that do not have any stations should be skipped.

The first section should be called "-" and should show the nearest station.

Example:

```
--A--
Astation C
Alaska C
Alabama C
--C--
Cstation
Cathedral station
Central station
```

So I got all this working but I feel like I am doing to much, there should be an easier way. Also, the app hangs for 1 second when loading this view on my iPhone 4. That no good either.
This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                                                                    target:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(searchBar:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;

    [rightBarButton release];

    UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    [mySearchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [mySearchBar sizeToFit];
    theTable.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ||
        UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
    {
        theTable.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 480.f, 44.f);
    }
    else
    {
        theTable.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 44.f);
    }

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
    [self setSearchDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
    [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];

    [mySearchBar release];

    /* Set the data */
    NSArray *stationenPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *stationenDocumentsDirectory = [stationenPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [stationenDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stations.plist"];

    NSDictionary* stationenDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
    xmlStationenList* stationsXml = [[xmlStationenList alloc] initWithDictionary:stationenDictionary];

    NSSortDescriptor *stationSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_station" ascending:YES];
    NSMutableArray *xmlResult = [stationsXml getTimeResult];

    NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stationSorter,nil] autorelease];
    [xmlResult sortUsingDescriptors:objects];

    [stationSorter release];

    /* prefName is decided by the page opening chooseStationViewController. Using this class init function */
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.prefValue = [prefs valueForKey:prefName];

    self.listContent = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (stationenListSet *theList in xmlResult)
    {
        [self.listContent addObject:[theList get_station]];
    }
    /* END set the data */

    /* Set sections */
    self.sectionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"-"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"A"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"B"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"C"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"D"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"E"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"F"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"G"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"H"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"I"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"J"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"K"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"L"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"M"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"N"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"O"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"P"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"Q"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"R"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"S"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"T"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"U"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"V"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"W"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"X"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"Y"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"Z"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"Å"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"Ä"];
    [self.sectionArray addObject:@"Ö"];

    [sectionSubArray release];
    sectionSubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *sectionTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"-"];
    [sectionSubArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] init]];

    for(NSString *sectionChar in self.sectionArray)
    {
        sectionChar = [sectionChar uppercaseString];
        int i = 0;

        NSMutableArray *sectionRowArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSString* theStation in listContent)
        {
            NSString *firstChar = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%C", toupper([theStation characterAtIndex:0])];

            if([firstChar isEqualToString:sectionChar])
            {
                [sectionRowArray addObject:theStation];

                i++;
            }

           [firstChar release];
        }

        if(i > 0)
        {
            [sectionSubArray addObject:sectionRowArray];
            [sectionTempArray addObject:sectionChar];
        }

       [sectionRowArray release];
    }

    self.sectionArray = sectionTempArray;
    [sectionTempArray release];

    [theTable reloadData];
    theTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [stationsXml release];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

The stupid thing I do is that I loop thru my array of over 300 objects for every letter I have. But I can't figure out a better way to do this.

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

**--------THE RESULT--------**
This is what the result became, thanks to all your answers:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                                                                    target:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(searchBar:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;

    [rightBarButton release];

    UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    [mySearchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [mySearchBar sizeToFit];
    theTable.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ||
        UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
    {
        theTable.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 480.f, 44.f);
    }
    else
    {
        theTable.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 44.f);
    }

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
    [self setSearchDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
    [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];

    [mySearchBar release];

    /* Set the data */
    NSArray *stationenPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *stationenDocumentsDirectory = [stationenPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [stationenDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stations.plist"];

    NSDictionary* stationenDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
    xmlStationenList* stationsXml = [[xmlStationenList alloc] initWithDictionary:stationenDictionary];

    NSSortDescriptor *stationSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_station" ascending:YES];
    NSMutableArray *xmlResult = [stationsXml getTimeResult];

    NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stationSorter,nil] autorelease];
    [xmlResult sortUsingDescriptors:objects];

    [stationSorter release];

    /* prefName is decided by the page opening chooseStationViewController. Using this class init function */
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.prefValue = [prefs valueForKey:prefName];

    self.listContent = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (stationenListSet *theList in xmlResult)
    {
        [self.listContent addObject:[theList get_station]];
    }
    /* END set the data */

    /* Set sections */
    self.sectionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-", @"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", @"Å", @"Ä", @"Ö", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *sectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"-", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"A", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"B",
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"C",
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"D",
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"E",
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"F", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"G", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"H", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"I", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"J", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"K", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"L", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"M", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"N", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"O", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"P", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"Q", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"R", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"S", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"T", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"U", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"V", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"W", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"X", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"Y", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"Z", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"Å", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"Ä", 
                                              [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], @"Ö", nil];

    [sectionSubArray release];
    sectionSubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSString *theStation in listContent) {
        NSString *firstChar = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%C", toupper([theStation characterAtIndex:0])] uppercaseString];

        [[sectionDictionary objectForKey:firstChar] addObject:theStation];
    }

    NSArray *keys = [sectionDictionary allKeys];
    keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];

    int indexPath = 0;

    NSMutableArray *sectionTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"-"];
    [sectionSubArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] init]];

    for(NSString *key in keys)
    {
        if ([[sectionDictionary objectForKey:key] count] > 0)
        {
            NSArray *subArray = [[sectionDictionary objectForKey:key] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

            [sectionTempArray addObject:key];
            [sectionSubArray addObject:subArray];
        }

        indexPath++;
    }

    self.sectionArray = sectionTempArray;
    [sectionTempArray release];

    [theTable reloadData];
    theTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [stationsXml release];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Loop over the stations and add them to the appropriate letter bucket. Should be 26 times faster.

Comment: I asked this in response to an answer, but just in case: what's with the C-style array syntax? Does that even work on NSArrays? Why not use the class's standard Objective-C methods like `NSMutableArray *sectionRowArrays = [NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:29]`, and `[[sectionRowArrays objectAtIndex:index] addObject:theStation]`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code with a fiew changes. These are the changes I made:

1) Use a local variable instead of loading sectionArray 26 times
2) Loop over stations once instead of 29 times

Did you leave some code out somewhere? sectionSubArray is not defined in this function, but appears to be a local variable. It is also never assigned to a property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(searchBar:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;

    [rightBarButton release];

    UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    [mySearchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [mySearchBar sizeToFit];
    theTable.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ||
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
    {
        theTable.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 480.f, 44.f);
    }
    else
    {
        theTable.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 44.f);
    }

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
    [self setSearchDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
    [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];

    [mySearchBar release];

    /* Set the data */
    NSArray *stationenPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *stationenDocumentsDirectory = [stationenPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [stationenDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stations.plist"];

    NSDictionary* stationenDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
    xmlStationenList* stationsXml = [[xmlStationenList alloc] initWithDictionary:stationenDictionary];

    NSSortDescriptor *stationSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_station" ascending:YES];
    NSMutableArray *xmlResult = [stationsXml getTimeResult];

    NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stationSorter,nil] autorelease];
    [xmlResult sortUsingDescriptors:objects];

    [stationSorter release];

    /* prefName is decided by the page opening chooseStationViewController. Using this class init function */
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.prefValue = [prefs valueForKey:prefName];

    self.listContent = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (stationenListSet *theList in xmlResult)
    {
        [self.listContent addObject:[theList get_station]];
    }
    /* END set the data */

    /* Set sections */
    NSMutableArray *sectionTempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.sectionArray = sectionTempArray;
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"-"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"A"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"B"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"C"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"D"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"E"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"F"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"G"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"H"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"I"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"J"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"K"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"L"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"M"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"N"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"O"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"P"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"Q"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"R"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"S"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"T"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"U"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"V"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"W"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"X"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"Y"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"Z"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"Å"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"Ä"];
    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"Ö"];

    [sectionSubArray release];
    sectionSubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sectionTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [sectionTempArray addObject:@"-"];
    [sectionSubArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] init]];

    NSMutableArray *sectionRowArrays[29];
    memset(sectionRowArrays,0,sizeof(NSMutableArray*)*29);
    for(NSString *theStation in listContent) {
        char currChar = toupper([theStation characterAtIndex:0]);
        uint8_t index;
        if(currChar == 'Å') index = 26;
          else if(currChar == 'Ä') index = 27;
          else if(currChar == 'Ö') index = 28;
          else index = currChar - 'A';
        if(!sectionRowArrays[index]) sectionRowArrays[index] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [sectionRowArrays[index] addObject:theStation];
    }
    for(uint8_t index = 0; index < 29; ++index) {
        if(sectionRowArrays[index]) {
            [sectionSubArray addObject:sectionRowArrays[index]];
            NSString *currChar;
            if(index == 26) currChar = @"Å";
              else if(index == 27) currChar = @"Ä";
              else if(index == 28) currChar = @"Ö";
              else currChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",index+'A'];
            [sectionTempArray addObject:currChar];
            [sectionRowArrays[index] release];
        }
    }

    self.sectionArray = sectionTempArray;
    [sectionTempArray release];

    [theTable reloadData];
    theTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [stationsXml release];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thnx. One problem though... error on memset(charCounts,0,sizeof(NSMutableArray*)*29); "error: 'charCounts' undeclared (first use in this function)" =S

Comment: Sorry, I changed variables and forgot that. Fixed.

Comment: Allright, no problems there. I don't know about uint8_t but I do know that that I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this row: [sectionRowArrays[index] addObject:theStation];

Comment: Two possibilities stand out. The first is that the index is out of bounds: aren't there supposed to be 30 pots? If that's not it my next question is *what the heck is going on here*? You can initialize NSMutableArrays and access their elements with C-type syntax? Does that even work? Even if so, why not use the class's standard methods? Like `NSMutableArray *sectionRowArrays = [NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:29]`, and `[[sectionRowArrays objectAtIndex:index] addObject:theStation]`, etc?

Comment: I used the example above, together with Matthew's comment (+1!) and created the result I posted into my question. Have a look! :) Thanks all!

Comment: @Matthew: I didn't use a pot for the '-', which is why there are 29, and I created a C-array of 29 NSMutableArrays since I know there will be exactly 29 spots and there could be empty spots between them.

Answer (score 1):

How about iterating over the list of stations and simply adding each to the appropriate 'bucket'?

If you don't need NSObjects and NSArrays, then you might consider using Standard Template Library' map<> template. But if you aren't familiar with that, then it may introduce more complexity (in terms of learning curve) than it's worth.

Short of that, how about an NSMutableDictionary with NSString keys being first letters and objects being NSMutableArrays.

I haven't done this - but it would reduce your 30x300 iterations down to 300.

Answer (score 1):

you need to profile your app's execution if you want to spend time improving code that takes time.

tip 1: use a unichar here, it will save hundreds or thousands of allocations:

```
NSString *firstChar = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%C", toupper([theStation characterAtIndex:0])];
```

tip 2: several of your collections are populated using incremental growth. it will help to reduce the number of grows/reallocs where possible. apple's second guessed you already, so their optimizations based on real-world use will work in your favor sometimes, but not likely all of the time. if you've over-allocated your collections during population, you can flatten them by creating a copy then disposing of the temporary.

tip 3: avoid autoreleased objects where possible. (seriously)

of course, you'll want to optimize your search/sort/populate algos as well.

but seriously, you must profile if you want to understand where your time is spent.

good luck!

Comment: +1 Great tips. I wanted to reiterate tip 3: only use autorelease where you actually have no other choice. Releasing it yourself the instant you no longer need it will reduce total memory use and (to a lesser extent) cpu load.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on to other answers as this is a much smaller thing and isn't nearly as important, but something that you should at least know.

This:

```
NSMutableArray *sectionTempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.sectionArray = sectionTempArray;
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"-"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"A"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"B"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"C"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"D"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"E"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"F"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"G"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"H"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"I"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"J"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"K"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"L"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"M"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"N"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"O"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"P"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"Q"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"R"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"S"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"T"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"U"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"V"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"W"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"X"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"Y"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"Z"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"Å"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"Ä"];
[sectionTempArray addObject:@"Ö"];
```

Can be replaced with this:

```
NSArray sectionTempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"-", @"A", @"B", 
    @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", 
    @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", 
    @"Å", @"Ä", @"Ö", nil];
```

Eliminates the need for a Mutable array (reducing overhead) and, if the compiler wouldn't optimize out those 30 addObject calls, speeding things up a bit. If you won't need to change the contents of the NSArray (or NSString or NSDictionary, etc.) after you initialize it, don't use the Mutable version if you can help it.

Comment: You need to add ,nil to the end of the call so that the method knows where to stop.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Oops, exactly right! That's what I get for posting while cooking dinner. I fixed the code.